# printing a table in rails

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to print only a table in rails view which have two div's and a table is in another div and the print image is in another div, and print the table overflow contents, cause when I am using window.print(); it print the whole page and also the images and leave the overflowing contents of a table.

Answer (score 0):

Separate CSS rules assigned to print media type